# What does 'even' mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

Even is one of those words with lots of meanings. It can mean divisible by two or flat/level.

But it can be used in a sentence such as this:

> Are you even listening?
>
> What time does the shop even close?

I realise how it makes a difference to the meaning of the sentence... but how? What does it actually mean something in this sentence? Does it *even* mean anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Even*** in this context is an adverb that is

> used to emphasize something surprising or extreme : *they have never even heard of the U.S.* | *they wore fur hats, even in summer*.  [NOAD]

It is merely a kind of intensifier, usually used to express the outrageousness of a thing. Now let's get down to cases:

> Are you even listening?

The speaker doubts you are listening and is rebuking you for your inattention.

> What time does the shop even close?

This one's a little harder, but probably someone has suggested the speaker go to this shop and the speaker doubts that it's open, or else someone has suggested that shop *may* be closed but the speaker is emphasizing the fact that the shop in fact stays open quite late. It would depend on context.

Answer (score 3):

The excellent blog Language Log talked about this use of "even" a while ago: [What does "even" even mean?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2943)